# how to create multiple topics and multiple table in kafka in jdbc connector?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

i tried to install kafka connect in command prompt .

i have a connector look like this

```
name=test-source-oracle-jdbc

connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector

tasks.max=1
connection.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.26.70.84:1621/OPICSDEV

connection.user=KFK_USER

connection.password=kafka_user012345

mode=bulk

topic.prefix=opics-demo

query=select * from OPICS.cust where rownum < 5

poll.interval.ms=900000
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read from multiple tables, you'll need to run multiple connectors at the same time.

Similarly, different topic prefixes could be provided as well within different Connector properties

Comment: Really? We run hundreds of connectors at once. Why can't you?

Comment: If you are using `connect-standalone`, then I'd immediately suggest that you use `connect-distributed` instead

Comment: really  ? i will try it tomorrow . thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: hi i used the connect-standalone but i got this error.

Comment: WARN could not get type for name com.amazonaws.auth.Signer from any class loader

Comment: That's just a warning, but JDBC Connector doesn't load any AWS classes anyway